# the api block gets called 2 times, leads in rendering component twice, though conditions are getting checked properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, setinterval, clearinterval

I am using 3 dynamic variable inside setInterval,
in state

```
this.state={
   checked: true,
   currentHash:"some current hash",
   updating: true
}
```

inside componentDidMount, i've done something like this

```
componentDidMount = () => {
        let timer
        timer = setInterval( (checked, currentHash, updating) => {
            try {
                this.setState({analysis:true});
                if(checked){
                    var generatedHash = "current generated hash";
                                if (currentHash !== generatedHash) {
                                    currentHash = generatedHash;
                                    if(updating){
                                        this.setState({updating:false})
                                        const updateResponse = this.props.sendFile(DOCUMENT_ANALYSIS, ""); // my api call
                                        
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        this.setState({analysis:false})
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    this.setState({analysis:false})
                                }
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    this.componentDidMount();
                }
                else{
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    this.setState({analysis:false});
                    this.componentDidMount();
                }
               
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.log("Event error", error);
            }
           
        }, 10000, this.state.checked, this.state.currentHash, this.state.updating)
    }
```

The interval is set to 10 seconds. But before getting correct state data, it is calling the same function twice.

Answer (score 0):

**you can try this or you can try react hook can be better**

```
  componentDidMount =()=> {
     this.time();
   }


  time =()=>{
      let timer
    timer = setInterval( (checked, currentHash, updating) => {
        try {
            this.setState({analysis:true});
            if(checked){
                var generatedHash = "current generated hash";
                            if (currentHash !== generatedHash) {
                                currentHash = generatedHash;
                                if(updating){
                                    this.setState({updating:false})
                                    const updateResponse = this.props.sendFile(DOCUMENT_ANALYSIS, ""); // my api call
                                    
                                }
                                else{
                                    this.setState({analysis:false})
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                this.setState({analysis:false})
                            }
                clearInterval(timer);
                this.componentDidMount();
            }
            else{
                clearInterval(timer);
                this.setState({analysis:false});
                this.componentDidMount();
            }
           
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log("Event error", error);
        }
       
    }, 10000, this.state.checked, this.state.currentHash, this.state.updating)
  }
```

Comment: Thanx for the response, but now the component keep on rendering without any check.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) of ReactJS:

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidMount(). It will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser updates the screen. This guarantees that even though the render() will be called twice in this case, the user won’t see the intermediate state. Use this pattern with caution because it often causes performance issues. In most cases, you should be able to assign the initial state in the constructor() instead. It can, however, be necessary for cases like modals and tooltips when you need to measure a DOM node before rendering something that depends on its size or position.

It appears that setInterval may be calling setState immediately.

Comment: Yes, it will render the componentDid mount called recursively.